# NSXMLParser Splitting an XML TAG Value

Tags: xml, swift2, nsxmlparser

I have the following XML data from a web service:

```
<ROWS>
<ROW>
<GroupBy>1</GroupBy>
<QUERY>
INSERT INTO TASKS_GVT([PK],[TaskYear],[TaskTypeId],[TaskElementType],[TaskPriority],[ElementId],[taskstatus],[TaskSubStatus],[AllocatedteamId],[PreRequisiteTask], [xloc],[yloc],[X],[Y],[Address],[TaskZone],[taskread],[clientid],[distance],[lastdistcalcdt],[ReplicateMe],[AllocationRequestTime]) VALUES ('3179543',2014,'19','1','2','107-08-106_421','3','6','380','0','0.0000000','0.0000000','44.4144000','24.5186000','الدوادمي ','421-0-0','R','0','0',GETDATE(),0,GETDATE())
</QUERY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<GroupBy>2</GroupBy>
<QUERY>
INSERT INTO RPTProblemTypes_GVT ([TaskYear] ,[TaskCode] ,[pbTypeId] ,[ReportDate] ,[INSTANCENAME] ,[PK] ,[ParentId] ) VALUES ('2015','3179543','754','Sep 11 2015 11:11AM','1-1086','380-1','1086')
</QUERY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
</ROWS>
```

I am reading the Web Service response using `NSXMParser` like this:

```
let parser = NSXMLParser (data: data!) //data is fetched using alamofire
```

delegate methods:

```
public func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String])
{
    tagElement=elementName
}

public func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String)
{

     if (tagElement.uppercaseString == "QUERY")
        {
            dataReturned+=string;
            print ("here dataReturned: \(string)")
        }
}
public func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?)
{
}
```

My Output is:

```
here dataReturned: INSERT INTO TASKS_GVT([PK],[TaskYear],[TaskTypeId],[TaskElementType],[TaskPriority],[ElementId],[taskstatus],[TaskSubStatus],[AllocatedteamId],[PreRequisiteTask],
here dataReturned: 
 [xloc],[yloc],[X],[Y],[Address],[TaskZone],[taskread],[clientid],[distance],[lastdistcalcdt],[ReplicateMe],[AllocationRequestTime]) VALUES ('3179543',2014,'19','1','2','107-08-106_421','3','6','380','0','0.0000000','0.0000000','44.4144000','24.5186000','
here dataReturned: الدوادمي ','421-0-0','R','0','0',GETDATE(),0,GETDATE()) 
here dataReturned: 
here dataReturned: INSERT INTO RPTProblemTypes_GVT ([TaskYear] ,[TaskCode] ,[pbTypeId] ,[ReportDate] ,[INSTANCENAME] ,[PK] ,[ParentId] ) VALUES ('2015','3179543','754','Sep 11 2015 11:11AM','1-1086','380-1','1086')
```

As you can see, I am only interested in retrieving the tag `QUERY`, but the output is wrong! The tag value is being split (i.e. `foundCharacters`  method is called more than once on the same tag) please someone help me with this issue.

what i noticed is that the this case is happening ONLY when there are arabic letters in the tag.!!!

thank you

Comment: if any more code is required please inform me

Comment: Anyone here might help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having difficulties with NSXMParser, use SWXMLHash which is a simple and better way obviously

https://github.com/drmohundro/SWXMLHash

i ended up doing something like this:

```
let xml = SWXMLHash.lazy(ReturnedData)

let Queries = (xml["ROWS"]["ROW"].all.map { elem in elem["QUERY"].element!.text;})

for Query in Queries
{
  print (Query)
}
```